# Add more values to the same key in dictionary(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a dictionary like

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, string>> dicCollection
```

How can I add more values to the same key in this dictionary?

Using C# 3.0

Comment: Which dictionary do you want to add values to, the inner or the outer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to add values to the outer dictionary in your example, you could use code like this:

```
if(dicCollection.ContainsKey(someDateTime))
    dicCollection[someDateTime].Add("key","value");
else
{
    Dictionary<string, string> newInner = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    newInner.Add("key","value");
    dicCollection.Add(someDateTime, newInner);
}
```

That will ensure that when a new key gets added to the outer dictionary, the inner dictionary won't be null (if it were null, calling Add would throw a null reference exception).

Comment: sorry , the post was not proper and henceforth the dictionary signature was not coming properly. I just modified that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want multiple values for a single key, you need to put the values into a collection or create an object which contains all the data members you need.

It might be easiest to just change your value to a List<>:

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> myDictionary;
```

Comment: sorry , the post was not proper and henceforth the dictionary signature was not coming properly. I just modified that.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a Dictionary where values are stored in a list. 
Something similar to:

`Dictionary<string,List<int>> dict` ...

Comment: sorry , the post was not proper and henceforth the dictionary signature was not coming properly. I just modified that.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary's keys and associated values are sets. You can't have multiple values to one key. The reason being is when you retrieve a value by key, only one value is being returned. How does the dictionary know which value you want?

You may want to implement the value type as a collection. That way you could retrieve more than one value associated to one key. So you could define it as let's say a list of objects for the value:

```
Dictionary<String,List<Object>> myDictionary;
```

That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will look up the entry in the outer dictionary and add a new entry to its inner dictionary. Is that what you want?

```
dicCollection[specificDateValue].Add(newKey, newValue)
```

Bear in mind that you should check first for the existence of specificDateValue by calling `dicCollection.ContainsKey(specificDateValue)`, and then do the same in the inner dictionary by calling its `ContainsKey` method with `newKey`.